# regex replace javascript return entire value

Tags: javascript, regex

I don't know why but my regex doesn't work...

```
$a = '_test[value][0]';
$b = $a.replace('/val/g','_');
```

Also i'm trying to do something a little complexe something like:

```
$b = $a.replace('/\[(.*)\]/g','_');
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Note that in JavaScript your variables don't need to start with `$`. This is something you might see reminiscent PHP programmers do, or people who don't quite understand jQuery.

Comment: `'_test[value][0]'` > `'_test[_ue][0]'`? Weird. What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove quotes from around the regex:

```
$b = $a.replace(/val/g, '_');
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expressions don't need quotes `$b = $a.replace(/val/g,'_');`

The only time you'd use quotes is to replace text with `jQuery.replace();`

eg: `$b = $a.replace('replace this','with this');`

(presuming that your code is jQuery based on the use of $)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to create the [Regexp object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) you are trying to use:

- From a string:

  ```
  var regexp = new Regexp('val', 'g');
  ```
- Using a Regexp literal:

  ```
  var regexp = /val/g;
  ```

Notice that the Regexp literal doesn't have any quotes, so when you use `'/val/g'` as your replacement you aren't actually using regular expressions, you will be trying to replace that literal string.

So you just need to drop the quotes:

```
$b = $a.replace(/val/g, '_');
```